# Add / remove nodes on button click Kendo UI Treeview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, treeview

I have following cshtml code. I want to add or remove nodes on button clicks. Can anyone guide me on that ?

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
        .Name("treeview-left")
        .DragAndDrop(true)
        .Items(treeview =>
        {
            treeview.Add().Text("Furniture")
                .Expanded(true)
                .Items(furniture =>
                {
                    furniture.Add().Text("Tables & Chairs");
                    furniture.Add().Text("Sofas");
                    furniture.Add().Text("Occasional Furniture");
                });
        })
    )

 @(Html.Kendo().Button()
        .Name("add")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "k-primary" })
        .Content("Add"))

    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
        .Name("remove")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "k-primary" })
        .Content("Remove"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use client side java script .

for removing node

```
$("#removeNode").click(function () {
        var selectedNode = treeview.select();

        treeview.remove(selectedNode);
    });
```

for adding node

```
var append = handleTextBox(function (e) {
        var selectedNode = treeview.select();

        // passing a falsy value as the second append() parameter
        // will append the new node to the root group
        if (selectedNode.length == 0) {
            selectedNode = null;
        }

        treeview.append({
            text: $("#appendNodeText").val()
        }, selectedNode);
    });

    $("#appendNodeToSelected").click(append);
```

code taken from http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/api

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined